# 'formatted_address' is null for some places, but not all ( Google Maps API ) Why is this?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API for JS and I have a bunch of markers on a map. I have some code to show the address and name of each marker on the map, but the address sometimes returns as undefined, but sometimes it does work.

```
function createMarker(place) {
    console.log("adding place " + place.name + " loc=" + place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6));
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
    var request = { reference: place.reference };
    service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent("<b>" + place.name + "</b><br />" + details.formatted_address + "<br /> <a href=" + details.website + ">Visit Website</a>");
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    });
  }
```

Sometimes, when I click on a marker (which is supposed to display the infoWindow), it throws an error instead of showing the window. The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatted_address' of null
```

Why is this happenning? If the code is right, is there a possibility that Google doesn't know the address of everything? Can someonne help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with this API for about 4 years, and this is pretty normal. Unfortunately, the Google Maps API is a black box, we can't do anything to fix it, but maybe you could contact them so they can provide you support

While they give you a response, I'd advice you to evaluate your variable for an undefined value to avoid getting and error

Comment: What do you mean by its a “black box”? Sorry, I’m an amerature

Comment: It's any complex piece of equipment or module, typically a unit in an electronic or software system, with contents that are unknown to the user

Comment: Oh, okay. When you said that I should evalulate my code for undefined values, do you think that its an error with the code? It works sometimes, so its probably not a code issue if it sometimes works, right?

Comment: Not enterily, the problem is that in some cases the API is returning a null value, so to avoid an errro you could check if (details!=null) you can go ahead and safely execute your method  infowindow.setContent to show the addres detail

Comment: Okay. Thank you.